# Linearization of Remez algorithm rational case

Tags: numerics, floating-point, approximation, regression

In the rational case, we are interested to find polynomials $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ s.t.
$f(x_k)-P(x_k)/Q(x_k)=(-1)^kE$ for $k=1,2,\ldots, N$ where $N=deg(P)+deg(Q)+2$

This can be rewritten as
$$
(1)~~~~~~(f(x_k)-(-1)^kE)Q(x_k)-P(x_k)=0
$$

The equation (1) is non-linear.
The notes in this [document](https://sites.tufts.edu/atasissa/files/2019/09/remez.pdf)
suggest using the following variation of the system of equations for linearizing (1).
$$
(2)~~~~~~((-1)^k E_0 - f(x_k))\sum_{i=1}^{q}b_i x_k^i+\sum_{i=1}^{p}a_i x_k^i + (-1)^kE=f(x_k)
$$

It seems quite different from (1). Is (2) above is the correct interpretation of (1)? How this was derived from the definition? Where the additional $f(x_k)$ and  $(-1)^kE$ come from?

Comment: I applaud anyone exploring this lovely field, its theory and its practical implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that this is Fraser and Hart's variant of the Remez algorithm.

Let us fix the constant term of $Q(x_k)$ to $1$:

$$
f(x_k) - \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{p}a_i x_k^i}{\sum_{i=1}^{q}b_i x_k^i + 1}=(-1)^kE
$$

from which we obtain
$$
f(x_k) + f(x_k)\sum_{i=1}^{q}b_i x_k^i - \sum_{i=0}^{p}a_i x_k^i=(-1)^kE\sum_{i=1}^{q}b_i x_k^i + (-1)^kE
$$

regrouping, we get

$$
(*)~~~~~~~\left((-1)^kE- f(x_k)\right)\sum_{i=1}^{q}b_i x_k^i + \sum_{i=0}^{p}a_i x_k^i + (-1)^kE = f(x_k)
$$

Since we don't know $E$, $(*)$ is not linear. The approach of Fraser and Hart is to make an initial guess $E_0$ so that $(*)$ becomes $(2)$ which is a linear system.