# Error curve does not oscillate in between reference points using Remez

Tags: numerics, approximation, regression

Using the Remez algorithm, implemented using multi-precision library, in certain functions that I want to approximate, the error curve does not oscillate in between reference points, and so no roots can be found (subsequently no extrema).

For example, this happens when I try to approximate $ln$ (natural logarithm) over the interval of $I=[a=0.5, b=1]$, with a rational polynomial $P/Q$ of degrees $n=deg(P)=6$ and $m=deg(Q)=5$.

For the first set of reference points, Chebyshev nodes are computed using the following:
$$
x_i^{(0)} = 0.5 \cdot (a + b) + 0.5 \cdot (b - a) * \cos(\frac{(2i-1)\cdot \pi}{2n})
$$
$$
i = 1,\ldots,N=n+m+2
$$

The figure below shows the first iteration of the error function with the first set of nodes marked in circles.
[image]

Next, the extrema are found:
[image]

The extrema, together with the reference points of interval bound, i.e., $x_a$ and $x_b$ compose the next set of reference points ${x^{(1)}}$

The following figure shows the error function in the second step, with the reference points marked with circles.
[image]

Here, the 7th and the 8th reference points are both below the x-axis and so no root will be found in between them. Regardless, this error curve has 10 extrema. Together with the two bounding reference points, there will be at most 12 new reference points which is less than 13, the minimum required for this approximation. So it seems that the error curve, in this step, does not oscillate enough. How this can be fixed so that more oscillation occurs?

Comment: Could you make the example more concrete by spelling out the function you are trying to approximate? In my experience *rational* approximation with Remez is a bit iffy. It is hard to reproduce the issue and diagnose the root cause just from the graph. You may want to try smoothly skewing the initial set of points to the left or right by exponentiation with a factor around unity (total range of maybe 0.5 to 2). I guess one could automatically skew based on the where the error function has the largest peak, but I do it by hand when needed.

Comment: Could you document in the question how you are picking the initial points, normalized to the interval $[0,1]$? It is easiest to discuss in terms of that interval; the points can be scaled to any interval $[a,b]$ in a separate step.

Comment: For a polynomial approximation $P(x)$ of degree $n$, one sets up $n+2$ linear equations of the form $P(x)-f(x) \pm E=0$, and uses the locations of the $n+2$ extrema of a Chebyshev polynomial of degree $n+1$ as the initial points $x_i$.  Same approach applied to rational approximation $P(x)/Q(x)$ would lead to equations of the form $P(x) - (f(x) \pm E)Q(x) = 0$, where the term $(\pm E)Q(x)$ makes the equations *non-linear*. How are you addressing this issue?

Comment: @njuffa Please see I have added details regarding your comments.
I tried skewing the set of points. Skewing them right (by using powers less than 1) the error curve becomes "flatten" while trying skewing them left does not move them by much, and in any case, the issue described still exists just in between a different pair of reference points.

Comment: @njuffa I use the Fraser Hart method addressing the non-linearity of the system.
See here I asked the same question and provided my own answer: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/36035/linearization-of-remez-algorithm-rational-case/36044
I use 0 as the inial guess and |E| (E derived from the solution to the system) for the subsequent steps.

Comment: Thanks for adding more detail. What you are doing seems to largely match what I use (W. Fraser and J. F. Hart, "On the Computation of Rational Approximations to Continuous Functions", *CACM* Vol. 5, No 7. July 1962, pp. 401-403 and 414), and trying your case right now, I see behavior similar to what you describe here. The problem would appear to be triggered by $\log 1 = 0$. The method can't handle it. That is what I meant by "iffy". State of the art (amazingly robust, per the paper): S.-I. Filip et. al., "Rational minimax approximation via adaptive barycentric representations", 2018.

Comment: For comparison: If I approximate $\log$ on $[0.5, 0.999999]$, minimize relative error, using skew factor of 1, everything seems to work properly, and I wind up with an approximation with a maximum error of around $3.436(10^{-15})$. I haven't tried yet how close one can get the upper bound to $1$ before things break down.

Comment: Here is what I see with my implementation. When generating a rational approximation $R_{5,6}$ to $\log x$ on $[0.5, b]$, I can take $b$ to at least $0.999999999999999$ without any issues when minimizing *absolute* error. Maximum error in resulting approximation is about $6\cdot10^{-6}$. When I minimize *relative* error, the error levelization is not working properly for $b > 0.99999995$ but correct error function oscillation is preserved. Without investigation I am inclined to believe the issue seen when minimizing relative error is due to some bug in my code.

Comment: @njuffa Thank you for testing in your implementation and the pointers. I will read this paper. However, I believe I found the source of the problem. I have found that the new extremes of the error function, in the second step, all are smaller than |E|. I did not handle such a case in my point exchange step. Does it mean something along the way is wrong or indeed it is something that may happen and I need to handle it in the exchange part?

Comment: @njuffa I have managed to get it working. Though I have improved the point exchange algorithm, it wasn't really necessary. The main issue was to adapt the next guess for E so that the decay in peaks of the error function will be minimized and the error function will be leveled. It converges now to log in the [0.5, 1] interval.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Congratulations! That is good to know, and confirmation that I have things to fix in my own implementation. Since self-answering questions is generally encouraged here in the spirit of knowledge sharing, consider posting an answer that lays out in some more detail how you successfully addressed the issue.